# диаграмма в tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, диаграммы

Мне нужно создать диаграмму в окне tkinter, не используя не встроенные библиотеки
диаграмма линейная

Comment: Начинать отсюда - [ask].

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой (академический) способ рисовать график, используя Canvas:

```
from math import *
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 1000, bg = "lightblue", cursor = "pencil")
canv.create_line(500,1000,500,0,width=2,arrow=LAST) 
canv.create_line(0,500,1000,500,width=2,arrow=LAST) 

canv.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```